# SwiftUI MapKit Drag Annotation

Tags: swiftui, annotations, mapkit, drag

Does anyone has experience or an idea how to drag & drop Annotations and Markers with the new MapKit Features released this year?

```
import MapKit
import SwiftUI

struct SwiftUIView: View {

    @State private var position: MapCameraPosition = .automatic

    var body: some View {
        Map(position: $position) {
            Marker("name", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 48.186915, longitude: 11.164182))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: We have no idea what your problem is

Comment: He wants to be able to drag and drop a `Marker`. In UIKit, you set `isDraggable` property of your `MKAnnotationView` subclass. In SwiftUI, we‘d expect to see a `Marker` that has `Bindable` coordinate parameter, but it’s not there (yet), AFAIK. Sadly, there are several `MKMapView` behaviors that haven’t made it to `Map`, yet.

Comment: If you want draggable annotation views, you probably have to resort to [`UIViewRepresentable`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/uiviewrepresentable/) or [`UIViewControllerRepresentable`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/uiviewcontrollerrepresentable), wrapping a `MKMapView`, and then go old school with `MKAnnotationView` subclass with [`isDraggable`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkannotationview/1452401-isdraggable) set to `true`.

Comment: You could try a different approach than Drag&Drop from presumably a list of markers.
 Instead, you could `add` makers at the chosen touch location (TapGesture)
 then use a `DragGesture` to
 drag the `Marker` around the map.
 This is simple to do with just a few lines of code in SwiftUI MapKit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import MapKit
import SwiftUI

private let rectWidth: Double = 80

private struct MarkerData {
    let coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
    let screenPoint: CGPoint

    var touchableRect: CGRect {
        .init(x: screenPoint.x - rectWidth / 2, y: screenPoint.y - rectWidth / 2, width: rectWidth, height: rectWidth)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var cameraPosition: MapCameraPosition = .automatic
    @State private var modes: MapInteractionModes = [.all]
    @State private var isMarkerDragging = false
    @State private var markerData: MarkerData?

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometryProxy in
            MapReader { mapProxy in
                Map(position: $cameraPosition, interactionModes: modes) {
                    if let markerData {
                        Marker("Start", coordinate: markerData.coordinate)
                    }
                }
                .onTapGesture { screenCoordinate in
                    self.markerData = mapProxy.markerData(screenCoordinate: screenCoordinate, geometryProxy: geometryProxy)
                }
                .highPriorityGesture(DragGesture(minimumDistance: 1)
                    .onChanged { drag in
                        guard let markerData else { return }
                        if isMarkerDragging {

                        } else if markerData.touchableRect.contains(drag.startLocation) {
                            isMarkerDragging = true
                            setMapInteraction(enabled: false)
                        } else {
                            return
                        }

                        self.markerData = mapProxy.markerData(screenCoordinate: drag.location, geometryProxy: geometryProxy)
                    }
                    .onEnded { drag in
                        setMapInteraction(enabled: true)
                        isMarkerDragging = false
                    }
                )
                .onMapCameraChange {
                    guard let markerData else { return }
                    self.markerData = mapProxy.markerData(coordinate: markerData.coordinate, geometryProxy: geometryProxy)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private func setMapInteraction(enabled: Bool) {
        if enabled {
            modes = .all
        } else {
            modes = []
        }
    }
}

private extension MapProxy {

    func markerData(screenCoordinate: CGPoint, geometryProxy: GeometryProxy) -> MarkerData? {
        guard let coordinate = convert(screenCoordinate, from: .local) else { return nil }
        return .init(coordinate: coordinate, screenPoint: screenCoordinate)
    }

    func markerData(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D, geometryProxy: GeometryProxy) -> MarkerData? {
        guard let point = convert(coordinate, to: .local) else { return nil }
        return .init(coordinate: coordinate, screenPoint: point)
    }
}
```

In this example, a marker is added by tapping to the screen and can be moved. If you need a preset marker you can add

```
.onAppear {
      self.markerData = mapProxy.markerData(coordinate: #YOUR_COORDINATE#, geometryProxy: geometryProxy)
}
```

Tested on macOS and iPadOS

Answer (score 0):

You could try this approach using `MapReader` and `dropDestination`, to allow dragging from a list of `pins` and drop them onto the map.

For example, with the mouse/finger, drag (long press) `pin-1` on the map.
Once on the map, you can drag the `pin` around the map.

Press the `Drag on/off` button to enable dragging of the `pin` or map functions.

Click/tap on a particular `pin` to select it, before dragging on the map with `Drag on`.

Here is a fully working example code for drag & drop Annotations using the SwiftUI MapKit.

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

struct PinPoint: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var name: String
    var coord: CLLocationCoordinate2D
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var isDraging = false
    @State var modes = MapInteractionModes.all
    @State var dragId = UUID()
    @State var pinList = [PinPoint]()
    
    @State private var cameraPosition: MapCameraPosition = .camera(MapCamera(centerCoordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 35.68, longitude: 139.75), distance: 4000.0, heading: 0, pitch: 0))
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                // just a button to turn on/off map dragging
                Button(action: { isDraging.toggle() }) {
                    VStack {
                        Image(systemName: "move.3d")
                            .resizable()
                            .frame(width: 25, height: 25)
                            .foregroundColor(isDraging ? .red : .blue)
                        Text(isDraging ? "Drag on" : "Drag off")
                            .font(.caption)
                            .foregroundColor(isDraging ? .red : .blue)
                    }.frame(width: 80, height: 60)
                }.buttonStyle(.bordered)
                Spacer()
                // list of pins to drop on the map
                ForEach(["pin-1", "pin-2", "pin-3"], id: \.self) { pin in
                    Text(pin)
                        .border(.red)
                        .draggable(pin)
                }
            }
            
            MapReader { reader in
                Map(position: $cameraPosition, interactionModes: modes) {
                    ForEach(pinList) { pin in
                        Annotation(pin.name, coordinate: pin.coord) {
                            Image(systemName: "mappin.circle")
                                .resizable()
                                .foregroundStyle(dragId == pin.id ? .red : .green)
                                .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
                                // tap on the pin to select it before dragging on map
                                .onTapGesture {
                                    dragId = pin.id
                                }
                        }
                    }
                }.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                // drag the pin on the map
                .gesture(DragGesture()
                    .onChanged { drag in
                        if isDraging, let ndx = pinList.firstIndex(where: {$0.id == dragId}),
                           let location = reader.convert(drag.location, from: .local) {
                            pinList[ndx].coord = location
                        }
                    }
                )
                // change the map mode so we can drag the pin or the map
                .onChange(of: isDraging) {
                    if isDraging {
                        modes.subtract(.all)
                    } else {
                        dragId = UUID()
                        modes.update(with: .all)
                    }
                }
                // receive the pin drop
                .dropDestination(for: String.self) { items, location in
                    if let pin = items.first,
                       let coord = reader.convert(location, from: .local) {
                        let pinPoint = PinPoint(name: pin, coord: coord)
                        pinList.append(pinPoint)
                        dragId = pinPoint.id
                        isDraging = true
                    }
                    return true
                }
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks that works. It is not very seamless/smooth dragging but it does the job.

Comment: yes, that is the behaviour of the drag&drop, I don't think you can
 change this. As I mentioned in my comment, you could use the alternative approach
 of tapping on the map to add a maker or such. Now you can easily code that,
 you have the tools, `MapReader` and `gesture(...)` to work with.